# Can I always open Google Maps links in OpenStreetMaps instead?

Tags: google-maps

From the Android courier app I use for work, the target address gets provided as a Google Maps link.

However I would much rather be using OpenStreetMaps (via an app like e.g. Guru Maps) instead. Is there a way how I can configure Android so that the Google links automatically get opened in an OpenStreetMaps app?

Comment: That depends on how courier app sends the data to the map app. This can be done using a general Google Maps link (`https://maps.google.com/...`), a special link with a protocol scheme provided by Google Maps (not sure if the GM app implements such a scheme) or in the end the app can search for the Google Maps app and directly send the map coordinates to it. If Courier uses option 1 or 2 then this might be possible if Guru Maps would also implement the URL Google Maps host or scheme. If it is option 3 you cant change it.

Comment: @Robert Is it possible to find out what option it is without contacting developers?

Comment: By decompiling the apps or may be by checking `adb logcat events`.

Comment: @Robert Ok, that doesn't sound like something I wanna dive into further. Thanks anyway!